# How to correctly perform django queries of ManyToMany fields

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset, django-2.2

I am working on an [IMDB Clone](https://github.com/pydatageek/imdb-clone) project for the sake of learning. It has two important models: Movie and Celebrity.

Movie model had three MTM fields all related with Celebrity model.

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    # .. unrelated fields deleted for code brevity ..

    directors = models.ManyToManyField(celeb_models.Celebrity, related_name='movies_as_director', 
                    limit_choices_to=Q(duties__name__icontains='Director'))    
    writers = models.ManyToManyField(to=celeb_models.Celebrity, related_name='movies_as_writer', 
                    limit_choices_to=Q(duties__name__icontains='Writer'))
    casts = models.ManyToManyField(to=celeb_models.Celebrity, through='MovieCast')
```

I would like to delete all three fields and add only one MTM field.

```
class Movie(models.Model):       
    # one 'crews' field takes the place of three fields ('directors', 'writers', 'casts')
    # but it shows bad query performance.
    crews = models.ManyToManyField(celeb_models.Celebrity, through='MovieCrew', related_name='movies')
```

And created an intermediate model which has some methods and a custom manager (which should do the magic).

```
class MovieCrewManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset()

    def get_directors(self):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(duty__name__icontains='Director').select_related('crew')

    def get_writers(self):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(duty__name__icontains='Writer').select_related('crew')

    def get_casts(self):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(duty__name__icontains='Cast').select_related('crew')


class MovieCrew(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='movie_crews')  #Movie Model
    duty = models.ForeignKey(celeb_models.Duty, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    crew = models.ForeignKey(celeb_models.Celebrity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # Celebrity Model
    role = models.CharField(max_length=75, default='', blank=True,  
                    help_text='e.g. short story, scrrenplay for writer, voice for cast')
    screen_name = models.CharField(max_length=75, default='', blank=True,
                    help_text="crew's name on movie")

    objects = MovieCrewManager()

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.duty in self.crew.duties.all():
            raise ValidationError('crew duty and selected duty should match', code='invalid')
        super(MovieCrew, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(MovieCrew, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.crew.full_name
```

The reason for decreasing the field count was the expectation for better performance. Because I call three different queries for all three MTMs which indeed go to the same model (Celebrity). However, for now I keep all four fields because I couldn't get the expected query performance.

There are four pages (views) listing movies with one listing template. Also I have created their counterparts. So I have a bunch of bad and a bunch of good performing pages to see the difference.

One of the views performing GOOD (three Movie fields: casts, directors, writers):

```
class MovieListMixin2(ListView):
    queryset = movie_model.objects.prefetch_related(
        'writers', 'casts', 'directors', 'genres', 'comments')
    template_name = 'movies/index2.html' 
    paginate_by = pagination


class IndexView2(MovieListMixin2):
    ordering = ('-release_year', 'title')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView2, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = '(GQ) Latest movies'
        context['title_suffix'] = 'by release date'
        return context
```

and its template (shortened for brevity):

```
{% for movie in object_list %}
[...]
<p class="small"><strong>Directors:</strong> 
    {% for director in movie.directors.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'celebs:celeb_detail' director.id director.slug %}">{{ director.full_name }}</a>, 
    {% endfor %}            
</p>
<p class="small"><strong>Writers:</strong> 
    {% for writer in movie.writers.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'celebs:celeb_detail' writer.id writer.slug %}">{{ writer.full_name }}</a>, 
    {% endfor %}            
</p>                
<p class="small"><strong>Stars:</strong> 
    {% for cast in movie.casts.all %}
        <a href="{% url 'celebs:celeb_detail' cast.id cast.slug %}">{{ cast.full_name }}</a>,  
    {% endfor %}            
</p>  
[...]
{% endfor %}
```

And the counterpart of the same view, but this is performing BAD (one Movie field: crews):

```
class MovieListMixin(ListView):
    queryset = movie_model.objects.prefetch_related('movie_crews', 'genres', 'comments')  
    template_name = 'movies/index.html' 
    paginate_by = pagination


class IndexView(MovieListMixin):
    ordering = ('-release_year', 'title')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = 'Latest movies'
        context['title_suffix'] = 'by release date'
        return context
```

and again its template (shortened for brevity):

```
{% for movie in object_list %}
[...]
<p class="small"><strong>Directors:</strong> 
    {% for director in movie.movie_crews.get_directors %}
        <a href="{% url 'celebs:celeb_detail' director.crew.id director.crew.slug %}">{{ director.crew.full_name }}</a>, 
    {% endfor %}            
</p>
<p class="small"><strong>Writers:</strong> 
    {% for writer in movie.movie_crews.get_writers %}
        <a href="{% url 'celebs:celeb_detail' writer.crew.id writer.crew.slug %}">{{ writer.crew.full_name }}</a>, 
    {% endfor %}            
</p>                
<p class="small"><strong>Stars:</strong> 
    {% for cast in movie.movie_crews.get_casts %}
        <a href="{% url 'celebs:celeb_detail' cast.crew.id cast.crew.slug %}">{{ cast.crew.full_name }}</a>,  
    {% endfor %}            
</p>        
[...]    
{% endfor %}
```

I don't get any errors from both implementations. On the other hand,

GOOD performing page has only **9 queries** executing in **2.42 ms**.

```
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_movie"
SELECT ••• FROM "django_session" WHERE ("django_session"."expire_date" > '''2019-10-03 02:20:13.197659''' AND "django_session"."session_key" = '''bftca58feksf1cbo17qzgc40l24eb893''')
SELECT ••• FROM "users_user" WHERE "users_user"."id" = '1'
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_movie" ORDER BY "movies_movie"."release_year" DESC, "movies_movie"."title" ASC LIMIT 5
SELECT ••• FROM "celebs_celebrity" INNER JOIN "movies_movie_writers" ON ("celebs_celebrity"."id" = "movies_movie_writers"."celebrity_id") WHERE "movies_movie_writers"."movie_id" IN ('8', '3', '7', '9', '6') ORDER BY "celebs_celebrity"."last_name" ASC, "celebs_celebrity"."first_name" ASC
SELECT ••• FROM "celebs_celebrity" INNER JOIN "movies_moviecast" ON ("celebs_celebrity"."id" = "movies_moviecast"."cast_id") WHERE "movies_moviecast"."movie_id" IN ('8', '3', '7', '9', '6') ORDER BY "celebs_celebrity"."last_name" ASC, "celebs_celebrity"."first_name" ASC
SELECT ••• FROM "celebs_celebrity" INNER JOIN "movies_movie_directors" ON ("celebs_celebrity"."id" = "movies_movie_directors"."celebrity_id") WHERE "movies_movie_directors"."movie_id" IN ('8', '3', '7', '9', '6') ORDER BY "celebs_celebrity"."last_name" ASC, "celebs_celebrity"."first_name" ASC
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_genre" INNER JOIN "movies_movie_genres" ON ("movies_genre"."id" = "movies_movie_genres"."genre_id") WHERE "movies_movie_genres"."movie_id" IN ('8', '3', '7', '9', '6') ORDER BY "movies_genre"."name" ASC
SELECT ••• FROM "reviews_moviecomment" WHERE "reviews_moviecomment"."movie_id" IN ('8', '3', '7', '9', '6')
```

BAD performing page has **22 queries** executing in **5.65 ms**.

```
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_movie"  
SELECT ••• FROM "django_session" WHERE ("django_session"."expire_date" > '''2019-10-03 02:54:13.177499''' AND "django_session"."session_key" = '''bftca58feksf1cbo17qzgc40l24eb893''')
SELECT ••• FROM "users_user" WHERE "users_user"."id" = '1'
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_movie" ORDER BY "movies_movie"."release_year" DESC, "movies_movie"."title" ASC LIMIT 5
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" WHERE "movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" IN ('8', '3', '7', '9', '6')
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_genre" INNER JOIN "movies_movie_genres" ON ("movies_genre"."id" = "movies_movie_genres"."genre_id") WHERE "movies_movie_genres"."movie_id" IN ('8', '3', '7', '9', '6') ORDER BY "movies_genre"."name" ASC
SELECT ••• FROM "reviews_moviecomment" WHERE "reviews_moviecomment"."movie_id" IN ('8', '3', '7', '9', '6')
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '8' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Director%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.   
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '8' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Writer%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.   
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '8' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Cast%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.   
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '3' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Director%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.   
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '3' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Writer%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.       
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '3' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Cast%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.       
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '7' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Director%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.   
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '7' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Writer%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.   
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '7' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Cast%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.   
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '9' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Director%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.   
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '9' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Writer%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.   
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '9' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Cast%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.   
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '6' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Director%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.   
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '6' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Writer%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.   
SELECT ••• FROM "movies_moviecrew" INNER JOIN "celebs_duty" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."duty_id" = "celebs_duty"."id") INNER JOIN "celebs_celebrity" ON ("movies_moviecrew"."crew_id" = "celebs_celebrity"."id") WHERE ("movies_moviecrew"."movie_id" = '6' AND "celebs_duty"."name" LIKE '''%Cast%''' ESCAPE '\')
  15 similar queries.
```

So, I would like your help.

1. Is it good to decrease three MTM fields to one MTM field?
2. If so, why it performs so bad? And why the model manager's method create duplicated queries?

Thank you.

PS: the project is open source and it is hosted on github as a repository. If you would like to see the living code, you can clone or download it.

It has initial data to load. Therefore, it would be easy to make it work in a few minutes. The db is sqlite3.

If you read this post in the future and want to see the code, I have added it as a branch. I hope I will not change it. https://github.com/pydatageek/imdb-clone/tree/query_comparison_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that every time you do `filter`, as you do in all the MovieCrewManager methods, it is *always* a trip back to the database - bypassing the `prefetch_related` optimisation.

I would approach this differently. Since you want all the data and are fetching it up front, you could write methods on Movie to use that cache if it exists and do the filtering in Python. Something like:

```
class Movie(models.Model):       
    def _get_crew(self, duty_name):
        if hasattr(self, '_prefetched_objects_cache') and 'movie_crews' in self._prefetched_objects_cache:
            return [c for c in self._prefetched_objects_cache['movie_crews'] if c.duty.name == duty_name]
        else:
            return self.movie_crews.filter(duty__name=duty_name)

    @property
    def directors(self):
      return self._get_crew('Director')

    @property
    def writers(self):
      return self._get_crew('Writer')

    @property
    def cast(self):
      return self._get_crew('Cast')
```

Then your view queryset could be:

```
queryset = movie_model.objects.prefetch_related('movie_crews__duty', 'movie_crews__crew, 'genres', 'comments')
```

and your template becomes:

```
{% for director in movie.directors %}
    <a href="{% url 'celebs:celeb_detail' director.crew.id director.crew.slug %}">{{ director.crew.full_name }}</a>, 
{% endfor %}
...
```

In my test this cuts down the queries to just 7.

Comment: your implementation made a great impact on bad serving pages. this also fits the rule "fat models, slim views". on the other hand, if there were no caching, it wouldn't achieve that performance. i would like to have more info on "_prefetched_objects_cache". thank you.

Comment: There isn't really any more info; it's not documented, but it's just the place Django stores the results of `prefetch_related`.